# Best way to make Django API call take longer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, timing, ddos

I have a Django application with an functional view API endpoint that returns a response fairly quickly. I would like to make this request intentionally take longer to return, for the purpose of avoiding DDoS attacks. I know it's possible to use throttling through DRF, but I was wondering what would be the best way to make the actual request take longer. Maybe add in a few expensive hashing functions?

Comment: `time.sleep()` with a random argument?

Answer (score 0):

time. sleep() is used to halt in python. I believe it would work on your case just before the result time sleep(30) that is used for delay. I think this will work for you!!!! Please use the throttling concept. It will limit the number of requests to a specific API.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).